# Can't remove local storage elements

Tags: javascript, local-storage, dom-events

I have a simple to do application with local storage. In my app user can create unordered list with new tasks. Last element in this app is local storage. I have a problem with this functionality.

Before I save the items in `localstorage` I can delete them using the button. I don't know why but it doesn't works after saving elements.

Any idea how can I fix it?

My code:

```js
const first= document.getElementById("first");
const second= document.getElementById("second");

function addList(e) {
  const newElement = document.createElement("li");
  newElement.innerHTML = first.value + second.value;
}

newElement.innerHTML += "<button> X </button>";
ul.appendChild(newElement);
store();

newElement.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeElement);
}

function removeElement(e) {
  e.target.parentNode.remove();
}


function store() {
  window.localStorage.myitems = ul.innerHTML;
}

function getValues() {
  let storedValues = window.localStorage.myitems;
  if(storedValues) {
    ul.innerHTML = storedValues;

    ul.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeElement);
}
}
getValues();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="first" name="artist" placeholder="Artist" />
    <input type="text" id="second" name="title" placeholder="Song title" />
    <button type="button" onclick="addList(event)">Add task</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="li-elements">        
  <ul class="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: First, it doesn't appear that your curly braces are correct in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you were just missing a few small things in ur code.  You were not properly adding the removeElement event listener when loading from localStorage, and you were not properly updating localStorage.  I have updated ur code so it works.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>




</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="first" name="artist" placeholder="Artist" />
            <input type="text" id="second" name="title" placeholder="Song title" />
            <button type="button" onclick="addList(event)">Add task</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="li-elements">
        <ul id="list" class="list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        function addList(e) {
            const first = document.getElementById("first");
            const second = document.getElementById("second");
            const newElement = document.createElement("li");
            newElement.innerHTML = first.value + second.value;
            newElement.innerHTML += "<button> X </button>";
            document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newElement);
            store();

            newElement.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeElement);
        }

        function removeElement(e) {
            e.target.parentNode.remove();
            store();
        }


        function store() {
            window.localStorage["myitems"] = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML;
        }

        function getValues() {
            
            let storedValues = window.localStorage["myitems"];
            if (storedValues) {
                let ul = document.getElementById("list");
                ul.innerHTML = storedValues;
                for (i = 0; i < ul.childNodes.length; i++) {
                    ul.childNodes[i].querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", removeElement);
                }
            }
        }
        getValues();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and all of the info!
Now, when I try to delete my items I have this error: 

```ul.childNodes[i].querySelector is not a function
```

Unfortunately, something is still wrong

Comment: I edited so u have the full working code.  I assume you might have had it out of order.  I would recommend wrapping ur initial  getValues() call inside an onReady function.